# How to make name field unique in laravel 6 validation

Tags: laravel

I'm using laravel 6 and I want to store data in `Offers` table in my database and make name field unique by validation.
this is my validation:

```
$validator = validator::make([$request->all()], [
    'name'=> 'required|max:100|unique:offers,name',
    'price'=> 'required|numeric',
    'details'=> 'required',
]);
```

The error I want to show is "This name has already been taken", but the error I get is "The name field is required". I don't know if I did anything wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SO .. read this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#manual-customizing-the-error-messages

Comment: `$request->all()` returns an array, you don't need to wrap it in an array, btw

Comment: Please don't use validator it was in Laravel 5, please use:
`$request->validate([
            // your rules
        ]);`
Other than that your code should work just fine, also as @lagbox said, don't wrap `$request->all()` in array.

Answer (score 2):

After you have define  rules for validation you can set message for each validation rules you have define when you call the `Validator::make` method like this

```
$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages = [
    'unique' => 'This :attribute has already been taken',
]);
```

Or specify message for a rule attached to a specific field

```
$messages = [
    'name.unique' => 'This :attribute has already been taken!',
];
$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

You can learn about more customization in the [**Validation: Customizing The Error Messages**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#manual-customizing-the-error-messages)